# ffmpeg video editor library is free to use in android?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, editing

I am developing video editor app. and i go through ffmpeg library and it's demo. It is really nice to use. but my question is it free to use? and if not then is there any other way for video editor like crop video, replace audio, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[`JavaCV`](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) uses Apache License, Version 2.0 and GNU General Public License (GPL). It provides wrappers from the JavaCPP Presets of commonly used libraries by researchers in the field of computer vision (OpenCV, FFmpeg, libdc1394, PGR FlyCapture, OpenKinect, videoInput, ARToolKitPlus, and flandmark), and provides utility classes to make their functionality easier to use on the Java platform, including Android.

Comment: i just want to ask that ffmpeg is free or paid?